# Is there a function in Mathematica to combine/decompose sinusoids?

Tags: functions, function-construction, fourier-analysis, trigonometry, built-in-symbols

Lets say I have some combination of an arbitrary number of sinusoids with potentially varying magnitudes, phase angles and frequencies that I would like to compose into a singular sinusoid, is there a fairly straight forward method of doing so? If not, how involved would it be to write a function that would do so?

Comment: Welcome to [Mathematica.SE]!  I'm not quite clear on what you're asking for.  Can you provide an example of what your "input" sinusoids might be and what you're looking for as output?

Comment: Have you seen [`TrigReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrigReduce.html) and [`TrigToExp`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrigToExp.html)? They may get you started.

Comment: …And TrigExpand, too.

Comment: Alternatively, you could look at things like FourierSinCoefficient and friends.

Comment: It is not completely clear what you want. Please give a relatively simple example.